# Карусель Slick: как добавить фиксацию одного слайда?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть карусель на основе плагина slick. Необходимо добавить функционал фиксации позиции любого слайда по клику (не более одного одновременно). Все остальные слайды должны двигаться сквозь него.
Пример: кликнули на слайд 3, он стал желтым, стоит на третьей позиции. Кликаем "Next", 3-й слайд стоит на месте, все остальные сдвинулись на одну позицию, т.е. видимый порядок цифр: 2 4 3 5 6... Таким образом, зафиксированный слайд всегда стоит неподвижно, на своём месте, в том числе во время анимации листания слайдера. Фиксация снимается по повторному клику, слайд остаётся на том же месте и двигается уже со всеми.

Если на базе этого плагина нельзя реализовать подобный функционал, подскажите, пожалуйста как это реализовать на JS?